# Adaptive Boosting vs. SVM

Tags: classification, svm, boosting

I am working on a binary classification case and comparing the performance of different classifiers.Testing the performance of `adaboost` algorithm (with decision tree as its base classifier) against `SVM` on multiple data sets I found that the `boosting` algorithm performs better.

The question I have is why this is happening? Is this because `boosting` always outperforms `SVM`? or it has something to do with the characteristics of my data set?  I wonder if anyone can help me with some potential explanations of such finding.

Comment: generally better, but not always. but that is just based on past experience. sure there are many papers comparing. and depends greatly on how rigorously models developed (how was boosted model tuned, which kernels tried etc.)

Comment: Thanks. Would be great if you could share the link of couple of those articles.

Comment: I was thinking of this paper: http://www.niculescu-mizil.org/papers/comparison.tr.pdf  (+/-problematic) But google will produce more: http://lowrank.net/nikos/pubs/empirical.pdf    I'm not convinced by these, hard thing to study, but have found that most practitioners will push for RF or boosting algorithms.

Comment: No problem. Not really a great answer, but hopefully useful. I also came across this while looking for stuff on heterogeneous ensembles: http://www.business-school.ed.ac.uk/waf/crc_archive/2013/42.pdf

Comment: You have not really been given proper answers though. One question certainly is if you use a non-linear kernel with the SVM and cross-validate the regularization parameter as well as the parameters of the kernel.

Comment: In addition, boosting decision trees is not AdaBoost, it is just that: Boosted Decision Trees. AdaBoost only uses decision stumps for the weak classifiers and only under this assumption the deriviation of the individual weights for the weak classifiers fit and the convergence guarantees on the exponential loss hold.

Answer (score 6):

For me your question is part of a larger one involving classification algorithms in general. This paper *Do we Need Hundreds of Classifiers to Solve Real World Classfication Problems?*, gets at this more fundamental question in finding that random forests outperforms all other competitors. A link to an ungated copy is here:

http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume15/delgado14a/delgado14a.pdf

There are other flavors of boosting that haven't been mentioned such as GBM, the generalized boosted model, which has an R package:

https://github.com/gbm-developers/gbm

Also worth a mention is XGBoost or extreme gradient boosting, which some have found to out perform everything (and despite the Delgado paper's findings).

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf

Comment: +1. And to emphasize, the OP's "always outperform" is problematic. Not just because of the No Free Lunch theorem, but because of specific issues like AdaBoost (and similar boosting algorithms) can perform terribly on data where the targets are mislabeled, while my guess is that SVMs would be more robust to that problem.

Answer (score 2):

In short: Regular AdaBoost (decision stumps, not decision trees as weak learners) usually outperform linear SVMs. Of course this is dependent on your data, data normalization, etc, so this is certainly not a general rule. The reasoning should be fairly clear. AdaBoost can learn non-linear decision boundaries, which is almost always helpful, especially if your data can not be linearly separated. If it can, it is all just a question of empircal results and not much can be said about AdaBoost vs. SVM except that the SVM builds upon Statistical Learning Theory (SLT, http://videolectures.net/mlss09uk_shawe_taylor_lt/?q=machine%20learning%20summer%20school). I am not entirely sure that can be said for AdaBoost. Given that the SVM maximizes the margin between the point clouds it should, given linearly separable data, outperform AdaBoost since we would expect better generalization from the SVM than from AdaBoost at this point.

*When the SVM uses a proper non-linear kernel that fits the data better and generalizes well, it usually outperforms AdaBoost.*

AdaBoost is commonly used because it is very fast. Viola  & Jones have used it 15 years ago to realize fast object detection, especially face recognition: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~efros/courses/LBMV07/Papers/viola-cvpr-01.pdf

In addition, please see my comments on your question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have used a linear SVM (i.e. an SVM with a linear kernel). Depending on the base learner, ADABoost can learn a non-linear boundary, so may perform better than the linear SVM if the data is not linearly separable. This of course depends on the characteristics of the dataset. See this page on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method) for more information about kernel methods.

Comment: I think the answer to the OP's question is implied here, but you aren't quite stating it explicitly. Can you spell out the answer to the OP's question?